# Does the war have an ending in Planetside 2?

Tags: planetside-2

As enemy bases are captured, they just seem to respawn right in the middle of friendly captured territory. This is looking like a perpetual cycle, and none of the three teams ever gets closer than to the very edge of winning the whole continent, only to lose lots of territory again.

So is this by design? Is Planetside 2 eternally to be at war, with no winner ever? I was hoping it would be more like a 'match'. I admit that both are almost the same thing, but there is at least the closure of winning/losing sides this way.

Comment: The other 2 continents get taken by a different faction everyday. Like on our server Indar was last taken by our faction, and now we are trying real hard to keep it that way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By design there is no end to the game. Factions can be pushed back to the warpgate but, no matter what, there will never be a victory. This won't ever change in the future either. It is one of the main points of the game and the one people have the hardest time to get used to.

A common question is: "If there is no 'victory', what is there to fight for?" and the answer to that is simply: "It's a sandbox. Set your own goal, find people to fight for the same goal and go for it. You decide whether you won or lost and even fighting losing battles can mean a victory for you personally."

Answer (score 6):

The game has changed since the previous answers. Now continents can be conquered, in which case the entire continent becomes held by that faction for a while, including all the warp gates, and other factions cannot spawn on that continent until the continent resets. Any remaining troops from before the conquest are still on the map though and can fight while they last.

Comment: Cool, haven't played in months so should check it out :)

Comment: A lot of details have changed in the last year. A new continent. A new aircraft type. Different resource system. New accomplishment tracking. Lots of other assorted changes and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Esimir and Amerish get conquered by one team practically every day.  Nothing special happens, besides the map screen displaying "last conquered by *<team name>*" in the corner.  At that point, most players from the winning team just move to a different continent, since there is nothing left to capture.

Indar does not usually get conquered, because there are so many more players playing on it.

Note that the continents cannot ever be *completely* captured, since it is not possible to take over another team's warpgate.

Comment: Don't forget the resource bonuses